# Can aria-describedby be placed before the input element?

Tags: forms, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

I have a form with `aria-describedby` attributes on the input alements, followed by a `span` tag with a description/example of the desired input. It also has class to only display for screenreaders (sighted people can make use of the `placeholder` information instead).

The issue here is that, according to Fangs at least, the screenreader reads the label, then prompts for input, *then* reads the `aria-describedby` text.

Can I move the text above the input in the code, e.g.

```
<label for="givenName">Given name</label>

<span id="givenNameHelp" class="help-block sr-only">e.g. Liam</span>

<input class="form-control" type="text" id="givenName" placeholder="Liam" aria-describedby="givenNameHelp">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly legitimate and will work with all screen readers